# How to re-index a php array having same set of data after a certain index?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array structure like mentioned below -

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 21
    [2] => Jason
    [3] => 20093350
    [4] => IGI
    [5] => Travel Deppt 
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 32
    [8] => Rosy
    [9] => 20094449
    [10] => ISC
    [11] => Invoice Deppt
)
```

I need a code/way through which I could get output like -

```
Array
[0](
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 21
    [2] => Jason
    [3] => 20093350
    [4] => IGI
    [5] => Travel Deppt 
)
[1](
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 32
    [2] => Rosy
    [3] => 20094449
    [4] => ISC
    [5] => Invoice Deppt
)
```

This would be appreciated if someone can advise the way to get this done.

Comment: where's your code attempt(s)?

Comment: I am new to PHP so could not get the way to go. Thats why I am asking help from you all.

Comment: `spent my whole day to get this ` Please edit the question to indicate what things you've found, been reading, tried etc.

Comment: @amitdutt24 I updated my answer after your modify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split an array in smaller arrays with [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

> array_chunk — Split an array into chunks

The second parameter set the maximum number of element to retain for each array generated.

```
$array = Array
(
    '0' => "1",
    '1' => "21",
    '2' => "Jason",
    '3' => "20093350",
    '4' => "IGI",
    '5' => "Travel Deppt ",
    '6' => "2",
    '7' => "32",
    '8' => "Rosy",
    '9' => "20094449",
    '10' => "ISC",
    '11' => "Invoice Deppt"
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_chunk($array, 6));
echo '</pre>';
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 21
            [2] => Jason
            [3] => 20093350
            [4] => IGI
            [5] => Travel Deppt 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 32
            [2] => Rosy
            [3] => 20094449
            [4] => ISC
            [5] => Invoice Deppt
        )
)
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Superb solution given. Thank you so much and sorry my question was ambiguous but still you understand ans answered well. Array [0][1] = 21 and Array[1][1]= 32 is Age.